# shellcheck vscode "shellcheck.ignorePatterns" for all files with no extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, shellcheck

I am using the shellcheck vscode extension and I would like shellcheck to ignore files *everywhere* that *do not* have a file extension. I have tried many different glob patterns and nothing works.

The closest I got was:

```json
  "shellcheck.ignorePatterns": {
      "*[!(.)]/**": true
  }
```

But it really wasn't close.

Does anyone know the magic sauce?

Comment: I'm searching the web on terms like *glob file no extension*, and the results don't look promising. What if instead you had a first entry like `"*": true`, followed by `"*.*": false`?

Comment: @noah Thanks for the input. Alas `"*": true`, followed by `"*.*": false` does not work. I found a decent solution that takes the opposite approach (inclusive) and does not use globs.

Answer (score 0):

*It seems that an extensionless file cannot be globbed.*

I ended up not using the vscode shellcheck extension and used an inclusive approach with `shellcheck` on the command line, offloading the task  of what to include to `find`.

All my scripts that needed to be linted were `.sh` files so this worked:

```sh
find . -type d \( -name node_modules -o -name vendor -o -path /tmp \) -prune -false -o -name '*.sh' -exec shellcheck {} \;
```

I would have liked to keep the bash linting in vscode but I had to settle for the above solution due to the limitation of globs/vscode.